# passing named slots to component using with createElement or JSX

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is is straight forward when using template syntax, however, when creating a component using `JSX` or `h()` this seems not possible.

#### Example:

##### Child component

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: "",
    };
  },
  props: {
    name: String,
  },
  render(h) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>DEFAULT SLOT:</h2>
        {this.$slots.default || " default slot missing"}
        <h2>NAMED SLOT:</h2>
        {this.$slots["named-slot"] || " named slot missing"}
        <h2>SCOPED SLOT:</h2>
        {this.$scopedSlots["scoped-slot"]
          ? this.$scopedSlots["scoped-slot"](this.user)
          : " scoped slot missing"}
      </div>
    );
  },
};
```

With a template I can do:

##### template-based component

```html
<template>
  <SlotComponent name="template">
    <template v-slot> Default</template>
    <template v-slot:named-slot> Named</template>
    <template v-slot:scoped-slot="user">
       scoped {{ user }}
    </template>
  </SlotComponent>
</template>
```

but with jsx, for obvious reasons, the slots are all passed to `this.$scopedSlots`

##### JSX-based component

```
export default {
  components: { SlotComponent },
  render(h) {
    const slots = {
      default: () => <h3> JSX default (doesn't work)</h3>,
      "named-slot": () => <h3> JSX named (doesn't work)</h3>,
      "scoped-slot": (user) => {
        return <h3> JSX SCOPED {user}</h3>;
      },
    };
    return (
      <SlotComponent scopedSlots={slots} name="template">
        <div> JSX Default (this works for default only)</div>
      </SlotComponent>
    );
  },
};
```

the `default` scope san still be passed as the child component, but I'm looking for a way to create the component using jsx or createElement that would create an instance where a named slot can be passed to `$slots` instead ot `$scopedSlots`

Comment: [Rendering slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#rendering-slots) part of the vue guide explains how to access `this.$slots`. Would this help?

Comment: @cSharp, that's vue3 documentation, I haven't tested this with vue3, since it's not applicable in my case, but the `h(MyComponent, null, {...slots})` syntax is not working in vue2, since the 3rd parameter is `VNodeChildren` which is just `VNodeChild[]` so it doesn't appear to support passing an object with slots

Comment: Right. Apologies. `vuejs2` tag complete missed me.

Comment: Can you change `this.$slots["named-slot"] || " named slot missing"` to `this.$slots["named-slot"] || this.$scopedSlots["named-slot"]?.({}) || " named slot missing"`?

Comment: @tony19 That would work as long as I have control over the child component. The problem is that this to example is only to illustrate the issue I have, but the child component in question is a library where I cannot do that.